# Auto resizing internal frame when main frame maximizes in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i am new to Netbeans Gui development 
i am trying to make gui almost like netbeans gui 
but internal framed do not re-size when i maximize the main frame . 
as there is no option of authorizing when i place Jinternalframes in Jdesktoppane using Grid bag lay out . 
with out using jdesktoppane netbeans give option of auto resizing horizontally and vertically.

I am not able to figure it out only desktoppane is resizing and other internal frames stay of same size

Comment: An internal frame will only resize when the frame is in a maximized state. You should NOT be use a layout manager for the JDesktopPane.

Comment: http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=151782#151782

plz visit this page here i have explained the problem with pictorial representation.

Comment: in the maximized state only the JDesktopPane use to auto resizes and the internal frames remains of the same size.
Actually after placing the Internalframes in JDesktopPane in the layout properties netbeans do not give Auto-resizing option for internal components.

Comment: if i do not place internal frames in JDesktopPane then i got option for auto resizing for each Jinternalframe and it resizes normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want JInternalFrames to resize when the parent does, you have to do it yourself. Using a layout manager will not do this for you and, like camickr says, you shouldn't be using one for a JDesktopPane anyway.

If you want to resize your internal frames, you need to set up a ComponentListener on the JFrame and use setBounds() to resize the internal frame to your chosen proportions.

```
@Override public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == yourFrame) {

        yourInternalFrame1.setBounds(0, 0, yourFrame.getContentPane().getWidth() / 4, yourFrame.getContentPane().getHeight());
        yourInternalFrame2.setBounds(yourFrame.getContentPane().getWidth() / 4, 0, yourFrame.getContentPane().getWidth() / 2, yourFrame.getContentPane().getHeight() / 2);

        // and so on
        // also can use yourDesktopPane instead of yourFrame.getContentPane()

    }
}
```

Comment: by using this code components will be displayed of same size in all screen resolutions or sizes ?

Comment: @andrewPk More or less yes. All doing this will do is set all of your internal frames to a certain proportion of the desktop pane. I guess there is one minor correction to my original example, you want to use the content pane, not the frame dimensions. Take your non-maximized screen shot proportions and reset all of the internal frames to those whenever the outside window is resized.

Answer (score 1):

> netbeans do not give Auto-resizing option for internal components.

There is no auto resizing property. There is a "maximized" property for each internal frame. Only one frame can be maximized at a time. In this case the maximized frame will automatically be resized with the desktop pane.

If you want all internal frames to be resized as the desktop pane resizes, then you would need to add a `ComponentListener` to the desktop pane and then manually resize each internal frame when the `componentResized()` event is generated.

> if i do not place internal frames in JDesktopPane then i got option for auto resizing for each Jinternalframe and it resizes normally

This is done by the layout manager of the panel that you add the internal frame to. A JDesktopPane is not designed to work this way. It is designed to let the user drag component randomly around the desktop.

Comment: would you plz. give me some code example this is what i want to do.
That each internal frame resizes according to its old size.
Thanks.

Comment: you got my problem plz. give me some example.
when i maximize the main frame all components in JdesktopPane get fit in the maximized window.
as they are fit before maximizing on all the screens of different resolutions.

Comment: Maybe you can use a GridLayout(). Each internal frame will be the same size. Although in this case the minimize and maximize buttons won't work properly so you would probably want to disable them.

Comment: actually minimize and maximize are working properly the only problem is with actual size of internalframe windows in non-maximized state.
I am not talking about the maximized sate of internal frame.